# upsample between two date columns

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have the following df

```
lst = [[1548828606206000000, 1548840373139000000],
 [1548841285708000000, 1548841458405000000],
 [1548842198276000000, 1548843109519000000],
 [1548844022821000000, 1548844934207000000],
 [1548845431090000000, 1548845539219000000],
 [1548845555332000000, 1548845846621000000],
 [1548847176147000000, 1548851020030000000],
 [1548851704053000000, 1548852256143000000],
 [1548852436514000000, 1548855900767000000],
 [1548856817770000000, 1548857162183000000],
 [1548858736931000000, 1548858979032000000]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns =['start','end'])
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
```

and I would like to get the duration of that event with start and end times per hour: e.g.
[image]

in my dummy df then for 6th hour should be 60 mins(maximum per hour) - 00:10:06 = 00:49:54. For 7th and 8th should be 1:00:00 each as the end time is 09:26:13. For 9th should be 00:26:13 plus all the intervals in the following .rows that overlap with 9th hour 09:44 - 09:41 = 3mins and 60mins -00:56 =4 mins. So the total for 9th should be 26+ 3 +4~=00:32:28

My initial apporach was to merge start and end, add dummy points every 3rd row,  upsample to 1S, get the difference between rows, sum up only the actual rows. There must be a more pythonic way of doing this. Any hint would be great.

Comment: [Please don't post images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), better is create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've been looking at your numbers for a few minutes now and I'm still not sure what you are asking. Is "Hour" in your second chart the hour of day? For example, is 16 == 4:00 pm?

Comment: Yes, thats right

Comment: @kostas how are you calculating duration?

Comment: in my dummy df then for 6th hour should be 60 mins(maximum per hour) - 00:10:06 = 00:49:54. For 7th and 8th should be 1:00:00 each as the end time is 09:26:13. For 9th should be 00:26:13 plus all the intervals in the following .rows that overlap with 9th hour 09:44 - 09:41 = 3mins  and 60mins -00:56 =4 mins. So the total for 9th should be 26+ 3 +4=33

Comment: Why is hour 7 duration  59:56?  Wouldnt it be 60:00, since the first event is from 6:10:06 to 9:26:13.13?

Comment: you are right but I make that clearn in the description. I have addes the comment above to the description

Comment: @kostas So your expected output dataframe is not total accurate with the given data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, something like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(pd.Series(1, index=pd.date_range(x.start, x.end, freq='S'))
                                     .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H')).count(), unit='S'), axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
2019-01-30 06:00:00   00:49:54
2019-01-30 07:00:00   01:00:00
2019-01-30 08:00:00   01:00:00
2019-01-30 09:00:00   00:32:28
2019-01-30 10:00:00   00:33:43
2019-01-30 11:00:00   00:40:24
2019-01-30 12:00:00   00:45:37
2019-01-30 13:00:00   00:45:01
2019-01-30 14:00:00   00:09:48
Freq: H, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Or to get it down to hours, try:

```
df.apply(lambda r: pd.to_timedelta(pd.Series(1, index=pd.date_range(r.start, r.end, freq='S'))
                                   .pipe(lambda x: x.groupby(x.index.hour).count()), unit='S'), axis=1)\
  .sum()
```

Output:

```
6    00:49:54
7    01:00:00
8    01:00:00
9    00:32:28
10   00:33:43
11   00:40:24
12   00:45:37
13   00:45:01
14   00:09:48
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: is there an easy way of applying this on the records of each ID in my df? I've tried to groupby and then apply it but i struggling to make ti work with that logic.

Comment: `df.appy(..., axis=1)` This will apply the logic to each row.